# breadth-first traversal of a tree in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree

I am trying to learn data structures well and implemented the following code for a depth-first traversal/application of a callback on a regular tree:

```
Tree.prototype.traverse = function (callback) {
  callback(this.value);

  if (!this.children) {
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
    var child = this.children[i];
    child.traverse(callback);
  }
};
```

How could I change this to make it breadth first instead?
This is what the Tree Class looks like:

```
var Tree = function (value) {
  var newTree = {};

  newTree.value = value;
  newTree.children = [];
  extend(newTree, treeMethods);

  return newTree;
};
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Fundamentally, the difference between DFS and BFS is that with a DFS you push the children of the current node onto a stack, so they will be popped and processed *before* everything else, while for BFS you push the children onto the end of a queue, so they will be popped and processed *after* everything else.

DFS is easy to implement recursively because you can use the call stack as the stack.  You can't do that with BFS, because you need a queue.  Just to make the similarity clear, lets convert your DFS to an iterative implementation first:

```
//DFS
Tree.prototype.traverse = function (callback) {
  var stack=[this];
  var n;

  while(stack.length>0) {

    n = stack.pop();
    callback(n.value);

    if (!n.children) {
      continue;
    }

    for (var i = n.children.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
       stack.push(n.children[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

And now BFS

```
//BFS
Tree.prototype.traverse = function (callback) {
  var queue=[this];
  var n;

  while(queue.length>0) {

    n = queue.shift();
    callback(n.value);

    if (!n.children) {
      continue;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i< n.children.length; i++) {
       queue.push(n.children[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You can replace the for with `stack = stack.concat(n.children)`

Comment: @AndrasSzell that would change the complexity of the algorithm from O( |V| + |E| ) to O( |V|^2 + |E| ), since concat() allocates a new array.

Comment: Array in JS is basically a hashtable, so there's no difference in complexity between concat and push.

Comment: No, an array is not implemented like a hash table.   You can use it like a hash, but JS implementations typically optimize arrays for array-like access.  HOWEVER... it makes no difference to the above -- allocating a new hash table would also change the complexity similarly, and the difference between concat and push is that concat allocates a whole new one, while push does not.

Comment: why in the first script you push the children in order, while in the second script you push the children in reverse order? That doesn't change almost anything

Comment: @Totty.js That's so I visit the children in the order I discovered them.  In DFS we pop from the end of the stack, so I want to first child at the end.  In BFS we pop from the front of the queue so I want the first child at the front.  It's not super important, but it's nice

Comment: Another option for the DFS for loop() using ES 6+ standards is: `n.children.slice(0).reverse().map((x) => { stack.push(x) });` (which adds the children to the stack in reverse order)

Comment: Note necessarily a recommendation or making any comment about time complexity, but certainly for lexical simplicity and cognitive simplicity, it should be noted that `push` takes a variable number of arguments as a rest parameter, so pushing an array of items into an array can be achieved with the spread operator. I would like to think the ES implementation can optimise this. `queue.push(…n.children);`