# Do you search in breadth- or depth-first in a recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Depth-first search uses LIFO/Stack.
Breadth-first search uses FIFO/Queue.
What does a recursive algorithm use? A combination of both?

Comment: Recursion uses the (call) stack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703019/breadth-first-traversal-of-a-tree-in-javascript/33704700#33704700

Comment: you've got it backwards: stack is FIFO, queue is LIFO.

Comment: Can BFS even be executed w/ recursion? I had thought it was only possible through iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a recursive algorithm always use Depth-first Search (DFS)

---

**Pseudocode**

**Input:** A graph G and a vertex v of G

**Output:** All vertices reachable from v labeled as discovered

A recursive implementation of DFS:

```
1  procedure DFS(G,v):
2      label v as discovered
3      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
5              recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

---

[Wiki source here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot!